# While Including Primary Keys as a property of my classes in C# using ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

If I supply a primary key property in my classes does Entity Framework implicitly iterate the value of newly created objects or do I have to supply code to register this information? This may seem obvious to some, and to be fair I researched this question to no avail before asking it.

Reason I need to know:

I need to retrieve a SelectList of items from a class, of which is a property of another class. The classes share a composition relationship in other words.

```
 // GET: Fora/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(db.Fora.OrderBy(m => m.MessageItem.TopicItem.Category), "TopicID", "Category");
    ViewBag.UserNames = new SelectList(db.Fora.OrderBy(m => m.MessageItem.From.UserName), "MemberID", "UserName");

    return View();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class ForumViewModel
{
    public int MessageID { get; set; }
    public Member User{ get; set; }
    public Topic Category { get; set; }
    public Message Message { get; set; }    
}

public class Message
{
    private List<Topic> categories = new List<Topic>();
    public virtual int MessageID { get; set; }
    public virtual int MemberID { get; set; }
    public virtual int ForumID { get; set; }
    public virtual int TopicID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }

    public virtual string Body { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public virtual Member From { get; set; }  
    public virtual Topic TopicItem { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Topic> Categories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set { categories = value; }
    }
}
```

Before anyone rips me apart for the class structure, I would just like to say I am a college student still trying to learn this stuff and out of desperation to get the action `create()` method of my controller to work I have hacked at this class trying to force it to work, also to no avail...

Any help or clarification is appreciated.

Comment: Would you like to make your question a bit more clearer?

Comment: Does EF supply information to the Identifier of my class if I create an object of the class, and purposefully don't supply the Identifier any information?

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean by "implicitly iterate the value of newly created objects" and "register this information" is actually adding the new objects to the database and getting EF updated about these, you need to take the steps to first create a new  object, add it to the dbcontext and then save the changes. Assuming the new object is of type `Message`,

first create a new `Message`:

```
var newMessage = new Message{ ... };
```

then add this to your dbcontext:

```
db.Message.Add(newMessage);
```

(where `Message` is the dbContext class that represents your Message table)

and finally save your changes:

```
db.SaveChanges();
```

The new `newMessage` object will get a new id after saving your changes if your db is configured to auto-increment the primary key value of your Message table.

Hope this helps.